# Creating a post in a group using an app token doesn't show up in the group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to test a Facebook integration where an application creates a group, sets a user as the admin (where the user has previously accepted *all* permissions for the app), and creates a post in that group (as the application, not the user). I've been testing this using the Graph API Explorer, and I've requested every single permission.

POST to `/{app_id}/groups` is successful: the group is created and the user is set as the admin of the group (me).

POST to `/{group_id}/feed` appears to be successful, returning an ID of a post. However, this post doesn't show up in the group's feed, and the permalink of the created post points to /pending. However, there aren't any pending posts (and approval is not required anyway).

I would expect that the app has permission to create a post in the group because the group was created by the app.

Why are these posts not be showing up?

Answer (score 1):

Apps need both `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` to be able to publish. You may find `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-manage_pages` useful.